# Does batch normalization require standardized input features?

Tags: neural-networks, batch-normalization

Is it standard operating procedure to preprocess features using feature standardization --- $x' = (x-\mu)/\sigma$ --- before training a neural net that implements batch normalization?

My intuition says yes definitely do this, normalization across the entire training set is different from normalization across a batch, but I wonder if there is community consensus on preprocessing or not when using batch normalization.